# Monkey Man Rewrite Analyzer says my rule will trigger but it doesn't

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I installed Monkey Man Rewrite Analyzer, i got a rule installed, it shows in the list, if i test it with monkey man it says it will fire but it doesn't in reality, whats wrong?

```
add_action('init', array($this, 'register_crr_jsonwebservice'), 99);

public function register_crr_jsonwebservice() {

    //Add the rewrite rule for this specific json controller
    add_rewrite_tag( '%ticket%', '([a-zA-Z0-9]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule( 'cjson/fullticket/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/', 'index.php?p=1312&ticket=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    flush_rewrite_rules();

}
```

Test this rule in MMRA:

> cjson/fullticket/231412tgsxcasfasdfas/

Works fine, test it out on wordpress directly copying the same url? 404, not found... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What's the hook? add_rewrite_tag needs to be hooked at least on init.

Comment: Sorry i added it a few seconds before you posted it, it's on init

Comment: Closing question as per OP request.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, can not debug your code, but this one works:

```
function register_crr_jsonwebservice( $wp_rewrite ) {            
    //Add the rewrite rule for this specific json controller
    add_rewrite_tag( '%ticket%', '([a-zA-Z0-9]+)');
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array(
        'cjson/fullticket/?([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . "?page_id=243&ticket=".$matches[1]
    ) + $wp_rewrite->rules;
} 

add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'register_crr_jsonwebservice' );
```

Do not call flush_rewrite_rules(); from this function - will lead to an error. And maybe add_rewrite_tag will have to be caled from separate function on init - have't tested that.

Comment: And what action is this bound to? If i bind this to init i don't get a parameter.

Comment: sorry for same mistake ;), I've edited the answer

Comment: Almost works, problem is, the ticket variable doesn't seem to be set, i just get redirected to the final url for page 1312 (i changed it from your example) the variables i pass are kept but my concern now is that it actually redirects the user, that is not my intent... I just want that a certain URL maps to a specific page, is this even possible?

Comment: For example: /cjson/fullticket/329457289fsdfasa351/?apikey=test&secret=test should map to /json/fullticket/?apikey=test&secret=test&ticket=329457289fsdfasa351 without actually redirecting... but now it is first of all dropping the ticket variable and then it is redirecting... If i were to POST or PUT on this url, i'm not sure it would create the desired operation

Comment: Sorry, but I probably don't understand your question. What is your goal? You do not want to get redirected? Rewrite rule is for redirection (like .htaccess). If you want to use Ajax - read about Ajax in Plugins: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: I'll close down this thread as it becomes confusing and open one that is clearer, you're free to pursue the discussion there...